# After I unzip a folder of images, I get an error when I try to delete the original zipped folder. Why?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, zip

Here's the pertinent codeblock:

```
            if item['mimeType'] == 'application/zip':
            print("Unzipping images into folder...")
            with zipfile.ZipFile(local_file_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
                zip_ref.extractall(local_directory) # Unzips the downloaded images into the specified folder
            zip_ref.close()
            os.remove(local_file_path) # remove the zip file after extraction
```

It correctly unzips it into the appropriate folder. However I get this error when I try to delete the original zipped folder. Is this a common thing and is there a good way to avoid this?

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "c:\Users\anton\Documents\python-scripts\download-image-folders-v1.py", line 133, in <module>
for image_folder_id in google_drive_image_folder_ids:
File "c:\Users\anton\Documents\python-scripts\download-image-folders-v1.py", line 126, in download_image_folders
zip_ref.close()
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\anton\\Pictures\\CURRENT IMAGE FOLDER\\9 Batches Part 1.zip'
```

Thanks!

Comment: As a side comment, the whole point of using `with ... as zip_ref` is so you **don't** need to call `zip_ref.close()` afterward.  Take that out.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `zip_ref.close()` statement.

Since you're using context manager (`with zipfile....`), the handler will be closed automatically once that block is finished.